# Can extractor hood be wired into oven terminal block?

Tags: electrical

I just threw out an old oven which had a separate extractor hood wired directly through it: Power -> Oven -> Hood.

Is this safe/legal? I notice that the cable between the oven and the hood is lighter weight.

I'm hesitant to simply wire the power and hood cables into the new oven's terminal block. Is it safe to do this like the hold oven, or should I get an electrician to properly wire the hood a separate appliance?

Just to be clear, I'm keeping the old hood and hob and just replacing the oven. The power running from the old oven powered the hood and the hob ignition.

Comment: Did the old setup have separate terminals for the hood?  It seems like a feature to me if it did— a feature that could power on the exhaust automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately the delivery guys took me by surprise and the old oven was taken away before I could open it up and look. The terminal block[s] where behind the metal casing, so I'm thinking it could well have been a feature the new oven doesn't have.

Comment: Is it a gas oven? **Are you in the UK?**

Comment: UK yes. Just electric oven with terminal block seemingly designed only for only one cable. I won't be wiring the hood into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To meet the electrical code in the U.S. (and most anywhere) all mains electrical connections must be done in an appropriate junction box **that has been tested and listed for the purpose**. As a rule, the terminal block and enclosure of an oven will have been tested for making connections to the oven cord. And it may be perfectly safe to add the hood cord as well since the box already meets requirements for flame retardance. For the sake of argument I'm assuming there is sufficient volume for the heat associated with the additional connection but that may not be the case. We don't need to figure this out because . . .

If controlling a hood is not a feature of the new oven then the terminal block box **almost certainly wasn't tested for this application and therefore the connection would not meet your local electrical code**.

The safe and correct thing to do is to wire the hood directly using an approved method (into a new or existing outlet or junction box). This may require changing or modifying the cord. If you are not comfortable doing this sort of electrical work then it makes sense to hire an electrician to do it. They would likely bill you the minimum for a house call plus materials.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm fairly sure the block is not designed for a second cable like you say, so I've not wired in the hood like before. I'll get an electrician to come and sort it out.